# Google places iOS sdk, get places by lat,long position

Tags: ios, google-places

I tried to get places on map with using Google Places SDK for iOS, and it works fine but inly with current device location with `currentPlaceWithCallback` method. I didn't find method which can return places array by lat and long. Could please somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Try this. https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/place-details

Comment: @BhavishaKhatri I'm sorry, but I still don't understand how it can help me get places array by current location on map?